# Change Div background with Javascript by ID when another Div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs that are generated in javascript, each given a unique id attribute whne it's created.

When the user clicks a Div I want to set the background and foreground color to indicate it's selected (I have that working).  When the user clicks another Div, I need to change the 1st one clicked back to normal.

Not sure how to do that.  Right now, when I click a div it changes, but then click another they both show the secondary colors.

I don't track the id of the original div when another is clicked.  Is this what I have to do?

I appreciate the help,

Comment: Check new class exists on another element other then currently user selected element. If so, then remove that class and add new class to the currently selected element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the click event, You can set the css class to the currently clicked div. This css class will have the background color you want.

```
.selected
{
  background-color:green;
}
```

before setting the css class on currently clicked item, Get the div(s) with the selected class name and remove that class from those.

```
$(function(){

  $(document).on("click","div",function(e){

     //Get any div(s) with css class "selected" and remove the class
     $("div.selected").removeClass("selected");

     //Set the css class to the clicked div
     $(this).addClass("selected");

  }); 


})
```

Replace the generic `div` with your specific jQuery selector

ex :

```
$(document).on("click","div.myDiv",function(e){

});
```

Where `myDiv` is the css class for your div's

[Here](http://jsbin.com/videzu/edit?html,css,js,output) is a working sample.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Perfect!